# Get value of other Component React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have this code in my `Login.js` :

```
<div className="row justify-content-start">
                <form className="form-signin">
                    <PageDetailsHeading name="Please Log-In to continue"/>
                    <EmailField/>
                    <PasswordField/>
                    <ButtonActor name="Log In" isPrimaryButton="true"/>
                </form>
            </div>
```

How can I get value of `EmailField` when I press `ButtonActor` ?

Here is my `EmailField.js`:

```
<div className="form-label-group">
                <input type="email" id="inputEmail" className="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autoFocus onKeyDown={this._handleKeyDown}/>
                <label htmlFor="inputEmail">Email address</label>
            </div>
```

Comment: in which component are you storing your state?

Comment: in `EmailField`

Comment: lift your state up in parent component, in your case in Login.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain state in `Login` component only,

```
state={email:''}
```

You also need to have a `onChange` handler and `onClick` in  `Login` component only and pass them to `EmailField` and `ButtonActor` respectively,

```
onEmailChange = (e) =>{
  this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
}
```

And

```
onButtonClick = () =>{
   console.log(this.state.email)
}
```

Pass the function to component,

```
<EmailField onEmailChange={this.onEmailChange}/>
<ButtonActor name="Log In" isPrimaryButton="true" onButtonClick={this.onButtonClick}/>
```

`EmailField` component,

```
<div className="form-label-group">
   <input type="email" id="inputEmail" className="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autoFocus onChange={this.props.onEmailChange} name="email"/> //notice attribute `name`
   <label htmlFor="inputEmail">Email address</label>
</div>
```

`ButtonActor` component,

```
<button onClick={this.props.onButtonClick}>Log In</button>
```

Comment: Btw, is there anyway to retrieve parent component's value ??

Comment: Which value you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry... I was thinking too much complex, when it can be solved easily ...

Answer (score 0):

You can provide that through mentioning that in the state of the component.